# mocking protected method

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I want to mock an inherited protected method. I can't call this method directly from java code as it is inherited from class that in another package. I can't find a way to specify this method to stub in in `when(...)`

```
package a;

public class A() {
    protected int m() {}
}

package b;

public class B extends a.A {
    // this class currently does not override m method from a.A
    public asd() {}
}

// test
package b;

class BTest {
    @Test
    public void testClass() {
        B instance = PowerMockito.spy(new B());
        PowerMockito.when(instance, <specify a method m>).thenReturn(123);
        //PowerMockito.when(instance.m()).thenReturn(123); -- obviously does not work
    }
}
```

I looked at `PowerMockito.when` overrides and this seems that they are all for private methods only!

How to specify protected method?

Comment: @AndroidKiller, updated code with class name. Actually they could be from Mockito, but I use powermock and these methods has the same meaning there

Comment: That's of the reason why we should always prefer composition over inheritance. If you can't just redefine this method in your tested code, just like you'll do with legacy code.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Nutshell: Can't always use `when` to stub spies; use `doReturn`.

Assuming static imports of `spy` and `doReturn` (both `PowerMockito`):

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(B.class)
public class BTest {
    @Test public void testClass() throws Exception {
        B b = spy(new B());
        doReturn(42).when(b, "m");
        b.asd();
    }
}
```

You could also `@PrepareForTest(A.class)` and set up the `doReturn` on `when(a, "m")`. Which makes more sense depends on the actual test.

Comment: wow, thank you. Interestingly when I tried to use Method instance instead of method string name stubbing failed with exception message about wrong number of arguments. But with string name all works perfectly.

Comment: @mishanesterenko Yep, it can get a little convoluted sometimes. Another option is always subclassing `B` for the purposes of the test. Not always an option, but less "magical" than modifying bytecode ;)

Comment: What would you do if you have set Methode returning void. Let's say `m` is a set-Methode like void m(MySpecialParser parser). This parser is used to parse my text. How can i mock it?

Comment: @Kayser Isn't there a doNothing? I don't recall off the top of my head.

Comment: Good answer.  FWIW: It pretty much follows the convention from [PowerMock's doc](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) (the "A full example of partial mocking of a private method" section applies to protected too).