# @WebMvcTest content is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test-mvc, springmockito

I've already read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377581/null-body-in-springboot-webmvctest) but it didn't solve the problem. I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE and I'm attempting to speed up my tests. Up to this point, I've used `@SpringBootTest` and I'm testing switching some of these simpler tests to `@WebMvcTest`.

My controller has the following method which is responding to `GET` requests.

```
public ResponseEntity<MappingJacksonValue> fetchOne(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam(value = "view", defaultValue = "summary", required = false) String view) throws NotFoundException {
    Brand brand = this.brandService.findById(id);

    if (brand == null) {
        throw new NotFoundException("Brand Not Found");
    }

    MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue = jsonView(view, brand);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(mappingJacksonValue, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

My test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(BrandController.class)
public class BrandSimpleControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private BrandService brandService;

    @Test
    public void testExample() throws Exception {
        Brand brand = new Brand(1l);
        brand.setName("Test Name");
        brand.setDateCreated(new Date());
        brand.setLastUpdated(new Date());

        when(this.brandService.findById(1l)).thenReturn(brand);

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api/brands/1").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is("Test Name")));
    }
}
```

When I run this test, I get nothing back in the content. I'm  not doing anything significantly different than [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/), so not sure what I'm missing.

I should note that using `@SpringBootTest` with the exact same controller works as expected.

Comment: when(this.brandService.findById(1l)).thenReturn(brand); shouldn't be  something like given(this.brandService.findById(1L)).willReturn(new Brand(1l)); ?

Comment: I've tried that as well and it gives me the same results of empty content.

Comment: Have you tried to add @AutoConfigureMockMvc after @WebMvcTest? I wrote a unit test for a rest-point for my own project. https://github.com/kometen/SpringBootWorldCities/blob/master/src/test/java/no/gnome/WorldcitiesApplicationTests.java

Comment: Have you ever try to run the test in debug mode?

Comment: Long story short, it had to do with some security stuff.

Comment: @Gregg if you still remember what the issue was, could you please [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)?