# Mockito When...thenReturn not returning expected value on Collection

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I'm doing a Mockito unit test on one of my service and I tried to mock it, but I cannot return the desired object. A snippet of my code looks like this:

```
   @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class RunBinaryApprovalActivityTest {

        @Mock
        CountryToMarketplaceMapper countryToMarketplaceMapper;

        @Test
        void doSomeTestHere() {
        Set<Integer> marketplaces = new HashSet<Integer>();
        marketplaces.add(1);

        List<String> countries = new ArrayList<String>();
        countries.add("US");




Mockito.when(countryToMarketplaceMapper.getMarketplacesForCountries(Mockito.anyCollection())).thenReturn(marketplaces);

Mockito.when(otherTestInstance.otherMethod("inputString")).thenReturn("ExpectedOutput");

Assert.assertEquals(otherTestInstance.otherMethod("inputString"),"ExpectedOutput");

Assert.assertEquals(countryToMarketplaceMapper.getMarketplacesForCountries(countries), marketplaces);


        }


    }
```

Right now the `otherTestInstance.otherMethod("inputString")` passed the test case but the `countryToMarketplaceMapper.getMarketplacesForCountries(countries)` failed because `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<[]> but was:<[1]>`.

I'm confused, didn't I just simulate the behavior of `countryToMarketplaceMapper.getMarketplacesForCountries(countries)` to return a `marketplaces` which has entry inside? I did some research and found this post: [Mockito when/then not returning expected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413337/mockito-when-then-not-returning-expected-value) and I chenged how I defined the mocking behaviour using "doReturn()...when()" but still doesn't resolve this issue.

I'm thinking maybe it's because thenReturn() cannot return a collection of thing but I didn't find any resource that explain this. If anyone know some hint, please let me know! Lots of thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what version of java and mockito you are using.
Try this

```
Mockito.when(countryToMarketplaceMapper.getMarketplacesForCountries(Mockito.anyListOf(String.class))).thenReturn(marketplaces);
```

Comment: It works! Could you briefly explain why your version works? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of mockito you are using ?

Comment: I believe I'm using 1.10.19.