# Mock Protected Parent Method When the Parent is in a Different Package and the Child Class is Abstract

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I need to mock a protected method in the parent class of my class under test but the parent class is in a different package. I thought that the solution would be to use `PowerMockito.spy()` but I cannot instantiate the type Child because it is abstract. There's gotta be a solution for this issue without refactoring.

Here's the Dependencies.

```
        <dependency org="org.powermock" name="powermock-core" rev="1.6.4"/>
        <dependency org="org.powermock" name="powermock-module-junit4" rev="1.6.4"/>
        <dependency org="org.powermock" name="powermock-api-mockito" rev="1.6.4"/>
```

This is legacy code so I cannot refactor, but here's the simplified code.

**Parent.java**

```
package parent;

public class Parent {

    // Want to mock this protected parent method from different package
    protected String foo() {

        String someValue = null;

        // Logic setting someValue

        return someValue;
    }
}
```

**Child.java**

```
package child;

import parent.Parent;

public abstract class Child extends Parent {

    String fooString = null;

    public String boo() {

        this.fooString = this.foo();

        String booString = null;

        // Logic setting booString

        return booString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time some dev writes `String xxx = null`, a kitten dies. Regarding the question, I read it 3 times and I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are asking. Are you asking how to instantiate an abstract class?

Comment: haha I just threw together a quick example. It is similar to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684328/mock-protected-parent-method-when-the-parent-is-in-a-different-package?rq=1) but I cannot use `PowerMockito.spy()` here because the class under test is abstract.

Comment: So I want to mock the `Parent.boo()` method and my class under test is `Child`. So I need to use `Mockito.spy(Child.class)` instead of `PowerMockito.spy(new Child())` because Child is abstract.

Comment: http://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.6.2/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#spy-java.lang.Class- ?

Comment: I want the answer to be in the form of implementing the solution in a JUnit test called `ChildTest.java` please.

Comment: I also want some gremlins to do my job but that's not the way it works..

Comment: I will throw together `ChildTest.java` soon to make my question more clear.

Comment: I usually have the [same structure in my tests as in my production classes](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AbstractTestCases). Meaning I have an abstract test which verifies common behaviour, and a concrete test for each class which (at least) instantiates the correct object under test and verifies any custom behaviour (if any).

Comment: Hint: you seriously want to read about the open/closed principle; and from there: rework your code to not be a bad design which leads to such testing problems. You see, if code is hard to test, it is most likely also hard to use, maintain and inherently smelly ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerMock to mock methods that are not public

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ChildTest {

   @Test
   public void testBoo() throws Exception {
      Child child = PowerMockito.mock(Child.class);
      PowerMockito.when(child, "foo").thenReturn("someValue");
      PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(child).boo()
      String boo = child.boo();

      //assert here whatever you want to assert
   }
}
```