# Do with Mockit something like MockUp from JMockit

Tags: mocking, mockito, powermock, mockups

I want to do something similar to 'MockUp' from JMockit but with Mockito.

I want to control the comportment of a method of a class that extends the class i want to test.
But i have one problem that is  the method is private, so i think i cant go with Mockito, and need use PowerMock.

The Problem

```
Class A extends B{...}

Class B {
  private Header generateHeaderForServiceCall(c,d,f,g,h,j){...}
}
```

In my Class ATest{ In @Before i want to mock generateHeaderForServiceCall(.....) for just return a default Header created for me. }

So, using JMockit is like:

```
new MockUp<Controller>() {
  @Mock
  private Header generateHeaderForServiceCall(...) {
    return defaultHeader;
 }
};
```

I will specify better my context:

```
public class B {
    private Header generateHeaderForServiceCall(Input A, Input B, Input c, Input D) throws ServiceException {
......
//do stuff
return header} 
}


public class A extends B {
    @Override
    public Response process(Request request) throws SOAException {
               //do stuff
        try {
            method_i_want_to_test(Input A, Input B);

            } catch (Exception t) {
                  throwCorrectException(t, logger);
     }
        return response;
 }

    protected Dossier method_i_want_to_test(Input A, Input B) throws 
       SOAException {
        ... //do stuff
        **Header** **header** = generateHeaderForServiceCall(Input A, Input 
             B,Input c, Input D);**

         // **doLogic** with header returned and return the result
    }
}
```

What im trying to do:

```
private A aTest;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.mock(aTest);

 PowerMockito.doReturn(defaultHeader).when(aTest,"generateHeaderForServiceCall", params);
    }
```

So, when i go to method_i_want_to_test and call the generateHeaderForServiceCall i just want to get a default header, and ignore the inputs and the logic of the method. I want to mock this method, but its private/protected.

- So, can i do with with Mockito?
- Do i need to use PowerMock?
- Can i use Mockito and PowerMockit together?

-------------------------------------- **UPDATE** ------------------------------

So, my classA, that i want to test is that :

```java
    package mypackage;

    import package.ClassB;

    @Service
    public class ClassA extends ClassB implements Xinterface {


        @Inject
        public ClassA(InputA inputA,  InputB inputB,InputC inputC,  InputD inputD) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public ClassAResponse process(ClassARequest request) throws SOAException {
            ClassAResponse response = initResponse(inputA, request, new ClassAResponse());
            ClassAInput input = request.getInput();
            ClassAOutput output = new ClassAOutput();
            response.setOutput(output);

            try {

                /*  */
                method_i_want_to_test(request.getHeader(), numberInput);

            } catch (Exception t) {
                throwCorrectException(t, logger);
            }
            return response;
        }

        protected Dossier method_i_want_to_test(Header srcHeader, Long numberInput) throws SOAException {

            Header header = generateHeaderForServiceCall(inputA,srcHeader,inputF,inputJ,inputK);

            OtherServiceRequest request = new OtherServiceRequest();
            OtherServiceInput input = new OtherServiceInput();
            input.setNumber(numberInput);
            request.setInput(input);
            request.setHeader(header); // So, you can see the i need the result of generateHeaderForServiceCall method

            OtherServiceResponse response = OtherService.process(request);
            assertSucessfullResponse(response, "OtherService");

            return response;

        }

    }
```

My ClassB that contains private and protected methods is that:

```java
    package otherPackage;
    ...

    public class ClassB {

        private Header generateHeaderForServiceCall(InputA inputA,Header srcHeader,InputF inputF,InputJ inputJ,InputK inputK) throws ServiceException {

            String[] nameInfo = QNameUtil.getServiceQNameInfo(inputA);

            String serviceVersion = auxMethod(inputJ, inputF);

            //... do more stuff

            return result;
        }
    }
```

And my class of test, where i do test for private methods with PowerMock and try with Mockito if the method is protected. After that i will explain what i got when i run both tests:

```java
    package package;

    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
    import org.mockito.Mock;
    import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
    import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
    import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
    import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
    import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.doReturn;

    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(ClassA.class)
    public class MyTest {

        @InjectMocks
        private ClassA classA;
        @Mock
        private InputA inputA;
        @Mock
        private InputB inputB;
        @Mock
        private InputC inputC;
        @Mock
        private InputD inputD;

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            classA = new classA( inputA,  inputB,inputC,  inputD);
        }

        @Test
        public void processPrivateMethod() throws Exception{
            defaultHeader = Aux.createDefaultHeader();

            //create the spy of my ClassA
            classA spy = PowerMockito.spy(classA);
            // Define what I want the method 'generateHeaderForServiceCall' returns when called
            doReturn(defaultHeader).when(spy, "generateHeaderForServiceCall", inputA,defaultHeader,inputF,inputJ,inputK);

            // I try to call the method 'method_i_want_to_test' with classA variable @Injected and with spy of ClassA
            //classA.method_i_want_to_test(defaultHeader,inputNumber);
            spy.method_i_want_to_test(defaultHeader,inputNumber);

        }
    }
```

1 - when I Run this the **processPrivateMethod** test in debug method, when the **generateHeaderForServiceCall** is called, it tries execute the logic of the method and fails because the header is a basic one. But what i try to do is mock this and just return the default Header without logic.

2- If i change the **generateHeaderForServiceCall** for protected like some methods of ClassB, and use mockito for that:

```java
    @Test
        public void processProtectedMethod() throws Exception{
            defaultHeader = JUnitTestUtil.createDefaultHeader();
            when(classA.generateHeaderForServiceCall(inputA,defaultHeader,"ccccccc","dxdx",5464564)).thenReturn(defaultHeader);

            classA.method_i_want_to_test(defaultHeader,inputNumber);

        }
```

But it return an error because the method is protected ( same error if it is private and i use mockito).

> Error: java: generateHeaderForServiceCall(....) has protected access
>   in package

Attempts:

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // Partial mock to mock methods in parent class
        child = new ClasseA(...){
            @Override
            protected Header generateHeaderForServiceCall(...) throws ServiceException {
                //mock logic here
                return aux.createDefaultHeader();;
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void processPrivateMethod() throws Exception{
        defaultHeader = aux.createDefaultHeader();


        //when
        Dossier bdoo = child.method_i_want_to_test(...);

    }
```

2-

```
@Test
    public void processPrivateMethod() throws Exception{
        defaultHeader = JUnitTestUtil.createDefaultHeader();

        child = PowerMockito.spy(new ClasseA(...));


       PowerMockito.doReturn(defaultHeader).when(child, "generateHeaderForServiceCall", context,defaultHeader,"ccccccc","dxdx",5464564);

        //when
        Dossier bdoo = child.method_i_want_to_test(...);
    }
```

3-

```
@Test
    public void processPrivateMethod() throws Exception{
        defaultHeader = JUnitTestUtil.createDefaultHeader();

        child = PowerMockito.spy(new ClassA(...));

        father = PowerMockito.spy(new ClasseB());

        PowerMockito.doReturn(defaultHeader).when(father, "generateHeaderForServiceCall", context,defaultHeader,"ccccccc","dxdx",5464564);

        //when
        Dossier bdoo = child.method_i_want_to_test(...);
    }
```

Noone do what i want. All go into generateHeaderForServiceCall method in classB and trying do the logic inside.
Thanks

Comment: In a standard `unit test` scenario you would not really change the behaviour of `non-public` methods. While my answer below explains how to do that technically, why do you feel the need to do that?

Comment: Hi. I edit my post, with some information and why I want to mock that method. Because I want to test one method of my class A, but it need the result of an external private method from class B, and I need mock this and control the return when he is called. Make sense?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to express with `external`, but in your previous example the method is `private` and in your more recent edit its `protected`. That makes a difference, so please be more specific and feel free to edit or remove the old part of your question.

Comment: Yeah, sorrry for that. So, unit testing is all about our class right? All dependencies, i call as "external" and we need to mock that. In your example, class B is one dependency/external and you mock it for return "123" right? But my problem is that generateHeaderForServiceCall is not a public method and mockito cant mock private methods. I will change protected for private, i thought the logic is the same. Its more clear to realize?

Comment: If its `private` I assume that the `method_i_want_to_test` is part of class `B` (as it won't compile otherwise). I'll update my answer.

Comment: No, **method_i_want_to_test** is parte of class A but in is logic it call the method **generateHeaderForServiceCall** that is part of Class B, private and i need the result of it for test the first method.

Comment: I've update my answer. I guess the principle is the same. If that still does not match your case provide a `compilable` example of the involved classes.

Comment: If `generateHeaderForServiceCall` is private and part of class `B` class `A` won't be able to see it, hence you can not use it in the `method_i_want_to_test` that is part of class `A`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but i cant mock the service. I created a file with my real code and i will update my post with it (no real names) for you see and explain the errors.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't see how your `ClassA` could possibly compile. Java should be unable to resolve `generateHeaderForServiceCall` as long as the method is `private`.

Comment: It compile. In my classB i have private and protected methods. This is a big project, and i was allocated to do unit tests to this. If you see the new MockUp<Controller>() example with JMockit, that fix the problem to protected methods. But i need to use Mockito/PowerMock to that.  Can you give me a example for a ClassB protected method with Mockito please?

Comment: Like if **generateHeaderForServiceCall** is a protected method.

Comment: If it compiles than your actual code must be different from the example you have added (thats just basic java visibility stuff). Anyway I restored the previous example with mockito from the edit history.

Comment: Thank you, i will try with protected. Just a question, why (@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)) ?

Comment: And, can I create an @InjectMocks of my classA and in the code create a spy of it? Or I need to create with @Spy?

Comment: Yes you can. The `Annotations` are matching to the normal methods. However I read somewhere that its not recommeneded to use both annotations (`@InjectMocks` and `@Spy`) on the same object. If you do it manually it should be fine.

Comment: Ty. For protected methods its necessary use @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class? I have the Junit 4 :/

Comment: I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684328/mock-protected-parent-method-when-the-parent-is-in-a-different-package) but I dont had sucess. It is exactly my problem with protected method in another package. I tried de override too, but noting...

Comment: If you look to the solution that i initially post `new MockUp<Controller>() {
  @Mock
  private Header generateHeaderForServiceCall(...) {
    return defaultHeader;
 }
};`, that is like a override of that method, but JMockit permit that with new MockUP. Can i do that with Mockito?

Comment: I update the code with 3 attempts without success

Comment: `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` is the junit5 equivalent to `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`.

Comment: First time you mention that your parent class is in a different package. I still think the key behind solving your issue is understanding how your real code for `ClassA` looks like. As long as you can not provide this information this discussion while go no where. (The linked `answer` should all work as well).

Comment: Thank you. I fix using the powermock @Spy and @PrepareForTest(value = {}) all class i need.  For the protected one.

Comment: Now i find another step that no make sense for me in ClassA, he is calling an inteface  `interfaceVariable.process(X)` but i cant mock that one. Firstly i override the method, but it still return NullpointerEx.

Comment: Anyway, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a [`spy`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.1.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy).

---

> So, can i do with with Mockito?
>   Do i need to use PowerMock?

If its private you need to use `PowerMockito`, 
if its protected `Mockito` alone could handle it.

> Can i use Mockito and PowerMockito together?

`PowerMockito` is build upon `Mockito`, so yes.

---

Note that `spy` should be used sparingly, for example for testing legacy code.
The usual recommondation would be to refactor your code.

The `@PrepareForTest` Annotation needs to include the `class` where the bytecode is modified in this case `Class A`.

---

**Private method mocking with `PowerMockito` and `JUnit4`:**

Here a simplified example using a `String` return instead of a `Header`:

```java
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Test.A.class)
public class Test {

    static class A extends B {
        public String process() {
            return "y" + method_i_want_to_test();
        }
    }

    static class B {
        private String generateHeaderForServiceCall() {
            return "abc";
        }

        protected String method_i_want_to_test() {
            return "x" + generateHeaderForServiceCall();
        }
    }

    @Spy
    A classUnderTest = new A();

    @Test
    public void testCustomExceptionIsThrown() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.doReturn("123").when(classUnderTest, "generateHeaderForServiceCall");
        Assert.assertEquals("yx123", classUnderTest.process());
    }
}
```

---

**Protected method mocking with `Mockito` and `JUnit5`:**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class Test {

    static class A extends B {
        public String test() {
            return generateHeaderForServiceCall();
        }
    }

    static class B {
        protected String generateHeaderForServiceCall() {
            return "abc";
        }
    }

    @Spy
    A classUnderTest;

    @Test
    public void testCustomExceptionIsThrown() throws Exception {

        Mockito.when(classUnderTest.generateHeaderForServiceCall()).thenReturn("123");
        Assertions.assertEquals("123", classUnderTest.test());
    }
}
```